# Implementation of Decoupling capacitor

Tags: rf, pcb-design, decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

I have schematic for decoupling capacitors (3 set of 0.1uF,1nF,10pF):
[image]
And I've implemented that in this way:
[image]
And there is ADI reference for easy evaluation:
[image]
And the ground pins of decoupling caps will all connected to ground by polygone containing all pins in top and bottom. Also we have two stranger, [12GHz differential pair](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415544/differential-pair-routing-impedance-and-balance-issue?noredirect=1#comment1027928_415544) + clock trace.
Is it acceptable? Do not tell anything and listen to the notes please.

### Note:

The board have 4 layer 1.RF 2.GND(unbroken) 3.AVDD(unbroken) 4.signal

And as you can (have to!) see I have connected 3 AVDD pins of IC, together (by polygon), but the 3 AGND's are exactly in left side of the differential 12GHz pair. Unfortunately I will connect the top capacitors to two pin in left-side of C1's GND, because they are GND but are Digital GND (datasheet called them DGND and SDGND).I have idea it will be nice if I can place a bigger size (like 1204) of one of capacitors to bridge the right and left of differential pair, is it good idea (I prefer 1nF)?

### Finally

The questions are:

|.Is it acceptable decoupling, rate it and if is poor give alternate idea

||.Is it good idea to bridge two side of differential pair? (because I think the bypasses must be between same GND & VDD but in this case they are not in good placement)

Comment: You do not have controlled impedances for 12 GHz traces   You are making obvious errors and asking the wrong question. with mm wavelengths

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I have calculated the impedance of 12 GHz differential traces by "Kicad" 's calculator and I think they are not important in this question since I want to ask another question exclusively for this differential trace, and please help me to improve my question.

Comment: What chip is this and what current spectrum noise is generated here and elsewhere?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I didn't made it yet, then I don't know how much noise is generated, I only want to know referring to my assumption,is this strategy of bypassing is correct or acceptable or not. the chip is adf5901. Still incomplete question?

Comment: You're going to need thermal reliefs on all of the component pads connected to the AVDD polygon. Otherwise you'll get tombstoning when the board is manufactured, since the polygon will suck away all the heat and won't reflow properly.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Thx for nice advise, is you mean: http://heros-electronics.com/upload/2017-08/24/CauseAnalysisTombstoneTroubleshootinginSMTAssembly-a1bf8.png

Comment: Then you need to compute the effective resonance of each cap with series 1nH/mm from Vdd for each cap with s parameters and use Rogers or suitable PCB with coplanar ground tracks for balance and a lot more learning on DFM

Comment: Tombstoning is caused by all these things: trace/board design, pad design,
component and board oxidation, solder paste, stencil
design, print process, placement process, and reflow
process. NOT just ONE thing

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I am pretty sure that is NOT an ADF5901, which is a 32 pin package... An ADF4159 looks more likely.

Comment: @DanMills sorry misspelled.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd Yes, that is an example of tombstoning

Comment: I would add AnalogGround vias all along that wide trace, and tie that wide trace to the underlying AnalogGround.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Do you mean "clock trace" in "wide trace"?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist grateful to your practical advice, how can I calculate 1nH/mm for Vcc since I've derived it from supply plane  by via?

Comment: roughly distance from IC pin to via + via inductance to gnd + power plane but depends on L/W ratio

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 In PCB I've attached, we have wide top layer plane, I'm not sure how to calculate it? I think L/W must use for it to calculate nH/mm. lots of via will reduce it's inductance, I can't understand "+ power plane".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly look at the eval board gerbers and copy them, not always perfect but usually a reasonable guide to how to decouple such things.

Secondly those packages look huge, (0805? 0603? something like that), for at least the smallest values you really want 0402 or even 0201 to get the package parasitic inductance down low enough.

How you ground the caps is **REALLY** going to matter, think LOTS of stitching vias.

Were I doing a from scratch design I might bury the RF feedback lines on layer 3 done as stripline with a local ground pour on L4 and L2 (And LOTS of stitching), so I could put the caps on L1 right above the rf lines, but it makes board stackup very important so you would not be able to use the cheap PCB pooling services.

Comment: Grateful to your inspiring idea, also can you give me your idea about 2 questions I've asked in "Finally"?